# Navigation Drawer Button next to Tablayout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-tablayout, drawerlayout

I want an `Appbar`/`Toolbar` that looks like the image below.

[image]

I don't need help with setting up `Tablayout` to work -I know that- 
but I am not very experienced with setting up `Appbars`/`Toolbars`.
`DrawerLayout` shouldn't also be a problem for me.

I already have code below, but I don't know how to continue.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tabs">

            //here are my tabItems

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_nav"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure which part you're having a problem with, but, basically, you just need to put an `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>` around the `<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike M. said you have to put a `Toolbar` around the `TabLayout`.
Then you have to do following in the activity:
First set the toolbar as ActionBar with `setSupportActionBar()`.
Then get the ActionBar with `getActionBar()` and call `setHomeAsUpIndicator()` with the Vector Asset `menu` on it.